# Calling variable from another function in python

Tags: python, function, variables

I have defined these two functions and I need to call income and allowance in function 2 from the first function, basically I want to calculate the finalIncome in function 2 (that line of code is commented). Heres the code:

```
def personalAllowance():
    income = int(input("Enter your annual salary: £"))
    allowance = 10600
    if(income>100000):
        for i in range (100000, income):
            if(income%2==0):
                allowence = allowence - 0.5
                if(allowence<0):
                    allowence = 0
        print("Personal Allowance = " + str(allowence))
    else:
        print("Personal Allowance = " + str(allowence))
    return (income , allowance)


def incomeTax():
    print("\n")
    #finalIncome = income - allowence
    print(finalIncome)
    taxBill = 0
    if(finalIncome <= 31785):
        taxBill = finalIncome * (20/100)
    elif(finalIncome > 31785 and finalIncome < 150000):
        taxBill = finalIncome * (40/100)
    elif(finalIncome >= 150000):
        taxBill = finalIncome * (45/100)
    print (taxBill)


incomeTax()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save references to those values and then subtract them:

```
income, allowance = personalAllowance()
finalIncome = income - allowance
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to call `personalAllowance` and assign the return value to something.

For example:

```
income, allowance = personalAllowance()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't actually need the "income" or "allowance", instead of returning a tuple, just return the difference as shown where I have commetned

```
def personalAllowance():
        income = int(input("Enter your annual salary: £"))
        allowance = 10600
        if(income>100000):
            for i in range (100000, income):
                if(income%2==0):
                    allowence = allowence - 0.5
                    if(allowence<0):
                        allowence = 0
            print("Personal Allowance = " + str(allowence))
        else:
            print("Personal Allowance = " + str(allowence))
        return income - allowance ## Just return the difference



def incomeTax():
    print("\n")
    finalIncome = personalAllowance()  ## This will return difference
    print(finalIncome)
    taxBill = 0
    if(finalIncome <= 31785):
        taxBill = finalIncome * (20/100)
    elif(finalIncome > 31785 and finalIncome < 150000):
        taxBill = finalIncome * (40/100)
    elif(finalIncome >= 150000):
        taxBill = finalIncome * (45/100)
    print (taxBill)


incomeTax()
```

Comment: Thing is I'll have to do other calculations as well in other functions, but for this, it works fine. Thanks!